# How to show loading state while waiting all my Firebase data requested completely done?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, loading

Happy Friday! I just want any advice on how to show loading as below:

[image]

while waiting Firebase data loaded completely.

I tried to use

```
<div *ngIf="!listOfFoodObject">
   <img [src]="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7luvR.gif" />
</div>
```

But still not success. Can anyone help me?

My current Firebase code in controller:

```
firebase.database().ref('menu_name').orderByChild('menu_name').once('value',(snapshot)=>{
    snapshot.forEach((snap)=>{
        this.listOfFoodObject.push({
            key: snap.key,
            menu_name:String(snap.val().menu_name).toUpperCase(),
            menu_image:snap.val().menu_image,
            description:snap.val().description
        });
    return false;
    });

});
```

---

and my `<ion-list>` view:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let food of listOfFoodObject">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left (click)="show_item_details(food.menu_name,food.key,food.menu_image,food.description)">
            <img src="{{food.menu_image}}">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2 (click)="show_item_details(food.menu_name,food.key,food.menu_image,food.description)">{{food.menu_name}}</h2>
        <p (click)="show_item_details(food.menu_name,food.key,food.menu_image,food.description)">{{food.description}}</p>
        <p>
            <ion-icon ios="ios-star" md="md-star"></ion-icon>
            3.8
        </p>
        <button ion-button round item-right (click)="show_item_details(food.menu_name,food.key,food.menu_image,food.description)">View sellers</button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a promise and wait for the resolve and while not resolved use the "waiting" image?

Comment: Actually, any ajax method will do; put the "waiting icon" in an active html element and set the property display to none when the ajax calls results in a success

Comment: promise and wait I do not know how to use it (^_^). Can you show me a sample code?

Comment: so, did it solve your problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var firebasePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // Do your database tasks, request data

    if(data was returned) {
        resolve(here you return your data);
    }
    else {
        reject(here you throw an error);
    }
});

firebasePromise.then(function() { 
    // this part deals with the resolved promise
    // so you can use your data here
}).catch(function() {
    // in here you handle your error that was returned by reject
})
```

This one above is a basic example of a promise, which is a specification to standardize an AJAX request, if you are using nodejs, angularjs or other libraries there are probably built-in promises that you can use, if not, you can look for a deferred object, which is pretty much a promise implementation.

You make a promise (firebasePromise) and the promise can either be resolved (your data returned successfully in an asynchronous fashion) or rejected. firebasePromise starts and work in the background and when it is done it fires the then method and it enables you to do operations on the returned values, resolved or rejected. This is an oversemplification but you can get the gist of it.

Comment: Ok thanks,,let me try first. I will give feedback later.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Firebase code, You may have initialized the listOfFoodObject as empty array

```
listOfFoodObject =[];
```

But empty array is "truthy" value and that's why in your following HTML code *ngIf condition is getting falsed and image is not getting displayed:

```
<div *ngIf="!listOfFoodObject">
   <img [src]="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7luvR.gif" />
</div>
```

You should initialize the `listOfFoodObject` as empty array just before your `forEach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

As said above use promises.

Use the code mnemosdev posted and you'll be fine.

But here's the catch on what you're doing, are you hiding the rest of page content while showing the loading gif? Because the user can click on anything in the page and even go back without response, it's bad UX.

Create a custom component [like this](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-custom-loading-component-in-ionic-2/) so when you're going to request something you call a method that presents the loding (without the *ngIf stuff) and when you ended it, having data or not, you call the method that hides the loading.

It's nbot a valid response for your question, but just thought you should know.